# Javascript or JQuery - How do I change the background color every fixed-time-interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Exact Duplicate:**
>   [how can I execute javascript code every a specific time interval ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836862/how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-every-a-specific-time-interval)

Is there an efficient method for causing a javascript (`ChangeDivBG()`, in my case) function to execute every fixed time interval?

Comment: hamlin, if that one wasn't enough, then how about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836862/how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-every-a-specific-time-interval http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914951/show-and-hide-divs-at-a-specific-time-interval-using-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511952/execute-function-every-nth-second http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081443/run-a-function-in-time-interval-in-jquery How many duplicates must there be before there are enough for people to find?

Comment: Voted to close, exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836862/how-can-i-execute-javascript-code-every-a-specific-time-interval

Comment: I apologise if my tone was too harsh, I find **far** too many people asking questions *before* they've tried very hard to find an answer by themselves, and I prefer (maybe wrongly on my part) to scold than to be gentle. Although I don't think I intended on that comment to be read as harshly as you may have read it; I apologise if there was a misunderstanding. You're right in general though, my attitude is rather miserable. I thought that's why I enjoyed working with computers and not people; but in that case I should stay away from SO.

Comment: I agree with your frustration. I think an appropriate discussion may be why didn't the exact duplicate show up in the auto-search when I posted the question? Perhaps it was my use of hyphens on fixed-time-interval. You can paste the question title into the ask-box of a new question and see for yourself -- nada.

Comment: I believe you. It's a known issue that SO doesn't have a good search facility (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/example-of-really-bad-search-in-so although there's a better meta discussion somewhere), but google works wonders with SO questions. I'm not aware of a valid reason not to google the same thing in 10 different ways to try and find an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setInterval(ChangeDivBG, 1000); // 1000 is time interval in miliseconds - 1000ms=1sec
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setInterval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval)

```
setInterval(ChangeDivBG, delay);
```

If you want to pass an argument:

```
setInterval(function(color){ ChangeDivBG(color) }, delay);
```

If you pass an argument like this:

```
setInterval(ChangeDivBG, delay, color);
```

It won't work in IE(under IE9), be careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval (func, t).

```
setInterval(ChangeDivBG, 1000)
```

t is in milliseconds.